# Combining formula using and / or in excel

Tags: excel-formula

Case 1
I have a set of data which i need to determine if the cell is in Business Hours or Not. 
8 - 18 (08:00 - 18:00) Business Hours (BH)
outside the timeframe is Non Business Hours (NBH)

Given Cell value for example is = "7" (which is NBH)
here is the formula i created =if(AND(C2>=8,C2<=18 ),"BH","NBH")

Case 2
I have a set of data for days in a week, i need to determine if the cell is in Weekdays or Weekends.
I have this formula = =if(OR(I2="Saturday", I2="Sunday"), "NBH", "BH")
note : i used the same variable name NBH - Weekends , BH - Weekdays

What I really need to do is to combine those two cases into 1 formula.

I need to output these scenarios correctly, listing below :

1. Time is 08:00, date is Saturday/Sunday = Combined formula of case 1 and 2 should output "NBH"
2. Time is 07:00, date is Monday-Friday = Combined formula of case 1 and 2 should output "NBH"
3. Time is 12:00, date is Monday-Friday = Combined formula of case 1 and 2 should output "BH"

Formulas can be seen in column BH/NBH WEEKDAYS and BH/NBH Weekends, you can browse attached file thanks much!
[Click to access the file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0nTbP434udrVklGOUFaUFJjMDQ)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to calculate it directly on the initital values:

```
=IF(OR(H2="Saturday", H2="Sunday", B2>18, B2<8), "NBH", "BH")
```

p.s. Alternatively you can combine the already calculated columns, if you intend to keep these columns:

```
=IF(AND((E2="BH"), (D2="BH")), "BH", "NBH")
```

Comment: @pnuts, :P How about `=REPT("N",SIGN(COUNTIF(D2:E2,"<>BH")))&"BH"`

Comment: @pnuts ah, I see now what you meant :)